# Requiring the same local node module from two directories results in two copies

Tags: node.js

I have a module (server.js) in the root of my project structure. It includes a module in a directory called lib:

```
var mongo = require('./lib/MongoUtils');
```

Another module in the lib directory also needs the 'MongoUtils' module, so it does:

```
var mongo = require('./MongoUtils');
```

The problem is I end up with two copies of the object (which is bad as it has some system resources like DB connections, etc.).

I've read the Node.js caching caveats documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats) and so it seems the problem is that I'm referring to the same module with two different paths and thus Node.js gives me two copies. Is this understanding correct?

How can I work around this? I didn't want to just dump my modules in node_modules since that's managed by npm via my package.json (and .gitignore-d). I thought about putting my local modules in the package.json (assuming that's possible), but then I'd need to be running 'npm install' whenever I make a change.

If this can't be done cleanly, I'll simply load the module in one place and pass it around, but that doesn't sound scalable if this occurs with lots of my modules.

Comment: The caveat is referring to that `require('mongodb')` might resolve to different files (if the module is nested inside node_modules for example). In your case if the first file is in one directory above lib and the second is inside lib, they should resolve to the same file. How do you know you end up with two versions?

Comment: If I call a method on one instance which sets some state and then check the state on the other, it's inconsistent.

Comment: Strangely, if I create a very small reduction test case, I don't see the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It turns out I typoed the capitalization of one of my modules. Node.js happily loaded the module and it worked fine, the only side effect was that I got the module loaded twice.

Here's an example. Note the capital B in the require statement in lib1.js.

main.js:

```
var lib1 = require('./lib/lib1')
    , lib2 = require('./lib/lib2');
```

lib/lib1.js:

```
var lib2 = require('./liB2');
```

lib/lib2.js:

```
function MyClass() {
    console.log('Constructor called');
}

module.exports = new MyClass();
```

If you run "node main.js" you'll get the following output:

```
Constructor called
Constructor called
```

If you fix the capital B in lib1.js and run it again, you'll see:

```
Constructor called
```

Comment: This is really a side effect of your file system being case-insensitive.  If you tried to run your project on a case-sensitive file system, your project would crash on startup because it wouldn't be able to find the misspelled module.