# Case sensitive issue in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have 2 files,
**extendableError.js**

```js
class ExtendableError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
    this.name = this.constructor.name
    this.message = message
    if (typeof Error.captureStackTrace === 'function') {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
    } else {
      this.stack = new Error(message).stack
    }
  }
}

module.exports = ExtendableError
```

**duplicatedError.js**

```js
const ExtendableError = require('./ExtendableError')

class DuplicatedError extends ExtendableError {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
  }
}

module.exports = DuplicatedError
```

Below is my testing code,

```js
const DuplicatedError = require('./duplicatedError');
const ExtendableError = require('./ExtendableError');
const ExtendableError1 = require('./extendableError');


try{
    throw new DuplicatedError('hahah');
}catch(err){
    console.log(err instanceof ExtendableError); // true
    console.log(err instanceof ExtendableError1); // false
}
```

The test is on  my mac book, why is that happen? Only the 1st charater was uppercase has different results. i don't understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097055/requiring-the-same-local-node-module-from-two-directories-results-in-two-copies https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats

Comment: I can understand 2 different modules, but still can't understand the different running results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for compatibility reason, macOS chose a case-insensitive file system. But it doesn't mean you have to bear it, `Disk Utility` can be used to reformat the partition to case-sensitive mode. If You do that, `node.js` will report error to you because of the wrong module name you are trying to `require`.

Then, let's talk about your test result. The key issue is which one you `require` in `duplicatedError.js`, if you change it a little bit:

```
//change the required name to lowercase extendableError
const ExtendableError = require('./extendableError')

class DuplicatedError extends ExtendableError {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
  }
}

module.exports = DuplicatedError
```

The test result will be:

```
false
true
```

You can even try to modify `duplicatedError.js` like below:

```
//change the required name to extENDableError
const ExtendableError = require('./extENDableError')

class DuplicatedError extends ExtendableError {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
  }
}

module.exports = DuplicatedError
```

The result shall be

```
false
false
```

So i think it's not about module caching, you have two things to be clear here:

1. macOX is case-insensitive file system by default
2. even you have only one file `extendableError.js`, but you `require` twice with different names, like: `require(./extendableError)`, `require(./ExtendableError)`, `require(./extENDableError)`, trey will be treated as three modules.

Comment: Got it. Thanks my lord!

Answer (score 2):

Macs are based on BSD UNIX, so the file system is case sensitive.

As a side note, it’s common to not use camecase for file names, eg:

```
  var extendableError = require(‘./extendable-error’)
```

Comment: but it doesn't report any error. If the file name is case sensitive, it should report an error if that file doesn't exist instead of showing these weird results.